# PHP Scandir Function with HTML Form (Checkboxes)

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, scandir

I have a directory that contains various files, .txt, .xls, .pdf, etc

I would like to be able to make a PHP script that uses the scandir function to fetch the filenames of every file in a particular folder, put them in an array and then pass that off to HTML so that it displays each file as a check-able box.

The idea is that the user visits the web page, checkmarks the files he/she wishes to open and then hits a submit button. Each file will open up (or will most likely prompt to be run/saved, which is fine).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: My friend, this is exactly a project! You should begin it, and then ask any questions on your issues. Not such a general question. It is a question that you should NOT ask. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = scandir("./");
foreach ($files as $filename)
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name="files[]" value="{$filename}" /> {$filename}";
```

Comment: Thank you sir - I will compare with what else I have been given